# Find equilibrium points maple

Tags: maple, differential-equations

I want to find the equilibrium points of the following differential equation in Maple:

```
y' = h(t-1) with h(t) = 1 if t>= 0 and h(t) = 0 otherwise
```

I tried using piecewise equations like this:

```
piecewise(t >= 0, h(t) = 1);
```

but I don't know how to continue because I need to solve for `h(t-1) = 0` and not for 'h(t) = 0`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Maple usage, not Maple programming.

Comment: @DrC would you care to elaborate on how those two differ? If I am using Maple or C or Java to solve a problem, am I not programming in Maple or C or Java and vice versa?

Comment: I agree it is somewhat subjective.  I'd say it comes down to things like logic and flow vs. just expressing the math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I follow your question entirely but will try.  First, define h as an operator

```
h := t->piecewise(t>0,1,0);
```

Then just solve for the zeros of the derivative?

```
solve(h(x-1)=0,x);
```

Which gives you the result `RealRange(-infinity,1)`  Hope this is what you want.